# How do I preventDefault on every object? Only first one worked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iteration

I am having trouble preventing default action of every Event object.
Each event should show a link that has a class id of 'ajax-event'. And links that have that id should have preventDefault() executed.

Here is the code in my Event.js file

```
function listenForEvent() {
 $('#ajax-event').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('you just hit event')
  event.preventDefault()
 });
};
```

And here is the iteration in my Events#index.html file:

```
<tr><!--this will list the details of the column name-->
  <% @events.each do |event| %>
    <% if event.event_guests.any? {|guest| !guest.rsvp }%>
      <td><%= link_to "#{event.name}", user_event_path(@user, event), id: "ajax-event", class: "ajax-event"  %></td>
      <td><%= event.location %></td>
      <td><%= event.date.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_event_path(@user, event) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Delete", user_event_path(@user, event), method: :delete %></td>
</tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

This preventDefault() action only worked on the first Event object. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple elements with the same ID in a single document is invalid HTML - when you select `$('#ajax-event')`, jQuery only looks to the first element with an ID of `ajax-event`. Remove the duplicate IDs (I don't see any need for any IDs at all here), and use your (already existing) class of `ajax-event` instead:

```
function listenForEvent() {
  $('.ajax-event').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log('you just hit event')
    event.preventDefault()
  });
}
```